# How to integrate Mobx State Tree with Vue JS?

Tags: vue.js, mobx, mobx-state-tree

I am building application on Vue and want to use Mobx State Tree as a store management library. I trying and finally made something working, but seems to it isn't work properly.

*First*, I have `Changer` component that change store via action. Works perfectly.
*Second*, I have `Test` component that tryes to react on store changes via passed props. Works fine only if I return prop via method.
*Third*, I have `BlindTest` component that tryes to react on store changes via `this.$store` itself and via `state` prop. Works fine only if I provide immutable snapshot as a `state` via function.

This is incorrect and strange behavior. Components updates only if props was changed, not if state was changed. Why?

Also I used `mobx-vue` library from official `mobxjs` repository for bindings between `mobx` and `vue`.

There is sandbox with demo application: https://codesandbox.io/embed/vue-template-ouq7r

Is there any way to connect MST and Vue properly?

Comment: But why?.. Doesn't Vue has it's own way?

Comment: We should have single source of truth for entire app. Vue has official Vuex which is lo-fi Redux without Sagas. Redux itself have some cons (big codebase, difficult time travel) and pros (sagas), when MST is a pure magic and finely integrated with TS.

Comment: Do you wrap/decorate your Vue components with `Observer` from `mobx-vue`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the official library: https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-vue